# How to return single record from database using fromMap in data model?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I'm trying to return a single record from a database using a data model that contains a fromMap function.  I know that I'm successfully retrieving information, but I can't seem to return it as a `VoterRecord`.  What am I doing wrong?  (Error is shown below.)

##### Get Single Record

```
  final data = await SQLiteMethods.getSingleVoter(voterId);

  

  static Future<VoterRecord> getSingleVoter(int voterId) async {
    final db = await SQLiteMethods.db();
    final tempList = db.query('Voters',
        where: "VoterId = ?", whereArgs: [voterId], limit: 1);
    return VoterRecord.fromMap(tempList[0]);    // ERROR at [0]
  }
```

**Error:** The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>>'. (Documentation)  Try defining the operator '[]'.

##### Voter Record Model

```
class VoterRecord {

  static const String voterIdTag = "VoterId";
  static const String firstNameTag = "FirstName";
  static const String middleNameTag = "MiddleName";
  static const String lastNameTag = "LastName";

  int? voterId;
  String? firstName;
  String? middleName;
  String? lastName;

  VoterRecord({
    this.voterId,
    this.firstName,
    this.middleName,
    this.lastName,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      firstNameTag: firstName,
      middleNameTag: middleName,
      lastNameTag: lastName,
    };
    if (voterId != null) {
      map[voterIdTag] = voterId;
    }
    return map;
  }

  VoterRecord.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    voterId = map[voterIdTag];
    firstName = map[firstNameTag];
    middleName = map[middleNameTag];
    lastName = map[lastNameTag];
  }
}
```

##### Code that does work

I know I'm retrieving information because this code does work:

```
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getVoter(int voterId) async {
    final db = await SQLiteMethods.db();
    return db.query('Voters',
        where: "VoterId = ?", whereArgs: [voterId], limit: 1);
  }
```

**Problem is that it doesn't return my results as a VoterRecord - and I really want it as a VoterRecord.**